# "HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation" error with type HTML

Tags: java, spring, web-services, exception

I have a simple controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/html", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> calculateHTML(@RequestParam(required = false) final String key){
String asd = "<html><head></head><body>Hello World!</body></html>";
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(asd, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
```

}

However, I'm getting org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation when i try to excecute the web service, since I'm learning with this simple example, i'm totally lost.

When I remove the produces "produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE" it works, however the output seems to be a json

Comment: "when i try to excecute the web service"
  
How are you executing this?